# c++ use default functions in class with same name

Tags: c++, function, object, redeclare

What would be a good approach to implement a class in c++ like this:

Someclass.h:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
       SomeClass();
       void kill();
}
```

Someclass.cpp:

```
SomeClass::kill(){
    kill();//This would cause an infinit recursion
           //How to fix it?
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is redeclare a function within my object as a method.
I can't find if there is a namespace or something simular, that contains "kill()", "sleep(int sec)".
Hope you can help.

Comment: Use the scope resolution operator to resolve scopes. By the way, your comment is wrong. It's infinite recursion.

Comment: "Here it would obviously throw an cannot call member function error" - no, it would recursively call `SomeClass::kill` and core dump.

Comment: Yes of cause you're right... I shouldn't just have pasted my trial ;)
Updated it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SomeClass::kill(){
    ::kill();
}
```

`::` accesses global scope